# How do you replace text with images within a html text box

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, frontend

I have a messenger application that allows users to send messages through a HTML text area. I have emoticons that I want to change the text out for when the right code is entered.

For example if a user writes "hi :)" the smiley face should be replaced with the image.

Is there a way to achieve this using Typescript & Angular2?

Comment: To clarify: you want the image to be created directly within a `<textarea>` or `<input>` tag?

Comment: Yep that's right. It should automatically replace the text in the <textarea> so you never actually see the code for the emote.

Comment: @SnowTurtle96 Normally the way people handle this is with an `emoji font library` (which is likely the easiest, but still not completely straightforward). Chose your custom font library, and then create a pipe that takes whichever characters and maps them to your custom font icon. There are a lot of SO questions explaining those two methods, so I'll leave the rest up to you.

Comment: Thanks, I had not considered pipes I will look into this!